# command not properly ended with multiple subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT s_fname
FROM (SELECT s_fname from student) as s_n
WHERE s_n like 'Youss%';
```

i get this error with multiple subqueries and cant get it right.
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: `WHERE s_n` should be `WHERE s_n.s_fname` I think

Comment: In Oracle, the `AS` keyword before a table alias is forbidden and is a syntax error. Remove the `AS` keyword and the "command not properly ended" error will be replaced with the next error (you also want `WHERE s_fname LIKE 'Youss%'`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT s_fname
FROM (SELECT s_fname from student) s_n
WHERE s_fname like 'Youss%';
```

Or try it this way:

```
with (select s_fname from student) as s_n
select s_fname from s_n
where s_fname like 'Youss%';
```

That said, other than as an exercise, there's no practical reason to use a subquery here. Better just to say this:

```
select s_fname 
from student 
where s_fname like 'Youss%';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT s_fname
FROM (SELECT s_fname from student) as s_n
WHERE s_n.s_fname like 'Youss%';
```

You're using a WHERE clause on a table, not a field

Also you could just write this instead in your particular case:

```
SELECT s_n.s_fname
FROM student as s_n
WHERE s_n.s_fname like 'Youss%';
```